# df.to_sql() Missing Optional Dependency: pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SOLVED:

I'm having an issue using sqlalchemy and snowflake.connector to push my df to a new table in Snowflake but I am prompted with this error:

`raise errors.MissingDependencyError(self._dep_name) snowflake.connector.errors.MissingDependencyError: Missing optional dependency: pandas`

Edit:
Accidentally posted without adding in more detail!

I am importing pandas, and all necessary packages. I do not understand why the error is suggesting pandas is missing as it is used elsewhere many times in my scripts.

Versions are:

`snowflake-connector-python     3.0.2`

`snowflake-sqlalchemy           1.4.7`

`SQLAlchemy                     1.4.49`

Below is a stripped out example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    user='service account',
    password='password',
    account='account',
    database='database',
    schema='schema',
    warehouse='warehouse',
    role="role"
    ))
df.columns = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df.columns)

df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=engine, schema="schema", index=False, if_exists='append', method=pd_writer, dtype={'field': String})

engine.dispose()
```

Solution:

Run the following in terminal/powershell:

`pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]`

Comment: What is your question ? Do you have trouble understanding the error message ? If so what do you not understand ?

Comment: @rochard4u sorry, added a bit more info now

Comment: Your issue is a little weird, could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Added a version of my code - cannot get more specific due to work-based project

Comment: I solved the original issue - had to run `pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the answer from the question to the answer section, so it doesn't look as unanswered:

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem for me

Comment: Can you start a new question with more context @PM0087?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing ***pyarrow***.

- I am using snowflake_connector_python==3.7.1, pandas==2.2.1, openpyxl==3.1.0.

I was facing the same issue, then It got resolved with pyarrow==15.0.2.